# How can use setUser() in react StreamChat?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

In my React(redux-saga) chat app, I am using StreamChat.
Error: {"code":12,"message":"Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL contains a fragment identifier ('%20UPDATE%20EACH%20MONTH%20WITH%20TRIAL%20IF%20NEEDED&authorization=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiODkyMTc2NjktZjIyNi00N2ZmLWJkODAtZjk5Y2NmOWQwMzUzIn0.73bYioWDU3kXsQZVGGPCCQItMq3RWBQnQYzsDBtcIj8&stream-auth-type=jwt&x-stream-client=stream-chat-javascript-client-browser-1.14.0'). Fragment identifiers are not allowed in WebSocket URLs."}

```
function* login() {
  try {
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      logo,
    } = yield select(getAuthUser);
    const name = firstName && lastName ? `${firstName} ${lastName}` : email.split('@')[0];
    const { id } = yield select(getFullAuthUser);
    const image = logo ? logo : `https://getstream.io/random_png/?id=${id}&name=${firstName}+${lastName}`;
    yield put(doLoginChat.request(id));
    const chatToken = yield call(getUserToken, id);
    const appKey = yield get(['REACT_APP_CHAT_KEY'], process.env);
    const chatClient = new StreamChat(appKey);
    
    yield chatClient.setUser(    //error was happened in this code
      {
        id,
        name,
        image    //image='https://getstream.imgix.net/images/random_svg/ST.png'
      },
      chatToken
    );
    console.log("success");
    yield put(doLoginChat.success(chatClient));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("aaa-e-failure", e);
    yield put(doLoginChat.failure(e));
  }
}
```

The 'id', 'name', 'image' and 'chatToken' value are correct, but error was happened in chatClient.setUser().
console.log("aaa-e-failure", e) => result: Error: {"code":12,"message":"Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL contains a fragment identifier ('%20UPDATE%20EACH%20MONTH%20WITH%20TRIAL%20IF%20NEEDED&authorization=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiODkyMTc2NjktZjIyNi00N2ZmLWJkODAtZjk5Y2NmOWQwMzUzIn0.73bYioWDU3kXsQZVGGPCCQItMq3RWBQnQYzsDBtcIj8&stream-auth-type=jwt&x-stream-client=stream-chat-javascript-client-browser-1.14.0'). Fragment identifiers are not allowed in WebSocket URLs."}.
I added the error image.

[image: error image]

Anybody can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that there is a hash `#` in your URL and you can't have that ([link](https://github.com/colyseus/colyseus.js/issues/40)).

I'm guessing that the `#` is coming from the same place as wherever you add `"%20UPDATE%20EACH%20MONTH%20WITH%20TRIAL%20IF%20NEEDED"` to the URL.  That is not in the code you've posted.  It's either in the `chatToken` variable and coming from `getUserToken` or the error is happening earlier at `yield put(doLoginChat.request(id))`.

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks for your answer. Could you tell me the answer to this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210010/chat-error-using-getstream-io-in-my-website ?